# What methods should a model contain

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, design-patterns, model

When I have a model `Car` where users can upload a single picture to, I can create a property `ImageFile` in Django to achieve that. Now I would also like to get the metadata from this file and save them to the database.

Now I'm very unsure where I should place this method a how I should design it. It would be obvious, to have a method like `_set_exifdata()` or `_update_exifdata()` that is called every time I set an Image to the model.

Or a method `get_exifdata(imagefile)` that returns a dict of exifdatas. But should this method be part of the Car model? Actually, I won't need it anywhere else, so it does not make sense to put it in a general helper class. But on the other hand, I would prefer to split methods in "retrieving data" and "setting data", so `_update_exif()` for example would do both of it in once, and maybe that's OK in design ways, but maybe its not and there is some rules of model design I should know and respect here.

I hope someone can help me with some guidelines for model design (especially for django) and what methods should be part of methods and which should not.

Answer (score -1):

if you using only for the car then you can put that value in the model save method, 
which will get call every time whenever you will update the data.